# C# I create a new Picturebox and now my Textboxes won't give me any values back

Tags: c#, controls, focus

I'm creating a new Picturebox via code, but now my TextBoxes don't give me any values. I think they went out of focus, or their controls aren't working anymore, here's the code so far:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int ErrorCode = 0;
        string NewName = NewPointName.Text;
        int X, Y;

        Application.DoEvents();

        if (NewPointName.Text == "")
            ErrorCode = 1;
        else
            for (int i = 0; i < Names + 1; i++)
            {
                if (PointName[i] == NewName)
                    ErrorCode = 2;
            }
        if (ErrorCode > 0)
            MessageBox.Show("Error " + ErrorCode);
        else
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(NewPointXBox.Text) > 60)
                X = 60;
            else if (Convert.ToInt32(NewPointXBox.Text) < -60)
                X = -60;
            else if (NewPointXBox.Text == "")
                X = 0;
            else
                X = Convert.ToInt32(NewPointXBox.Text);

            if (Convert.ToInt32(NewPointYBox.Text) > 60)
                Y = 60;
            else if (Convert.ToInt32(NewPointYBox.Text) < -60)
                Y = -60;
            else if (NewPointYBox.Text == "")
                Y = 0;
            else
                Y = Convert.ToInt32(NewPointYBox.Text);

            Punkt.GiveName(NewName, Names);
            Punkt.GiveCoordinates(X, Y, Names);
            PointName[Names] = NewName;
            NewPointName.Text = "";
            NewPointXBox.Text = "";
            NewPointYBox.Text = "";
            Application.DoEvents();
            UpdatePoint();
            CreatePoint(X, Y, NewName, Names);
            Names++;
            ErrorCode = 0;
            NewName = "";
        }


    }

 public void CreatePoint(int X, int Y, string name, int i)
        {
            int StartPointX = 450, StartPointY = 450, Factor = 7;
            if (RadioG6060.Checked)
            {
                StartPointX = 454;
                StartPointY = 449;
                Factor = 7;
            }

            Dot[i] = new PictureBox();
            this.Controls.Add(Dot[i]);
            Dot[i].Name = "PB_" + name;
            Dot[i].Size = new Size(10, 10);
            Dot[i].Image = Image.FromFile("../Dot.png");
            Dot[i].Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left;
            Dot[i].Location = new Point(StartPointX, StartPointY);
            Dot[i].Visible = true;
            InitializeComponent();
            Dot[i].BringToFront();
            Dot[i].Location = new Point(Dot[i].Location.X + (X * Factor), Dot[i].Location.Y - (Y * Factor));
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
```

I think it's the `this.controls.Add(Dot[i])` that throws it off, because now I can't access the text in my NewPointName textbox.

How can I focus the program back on the form or do generally anything that could activate the boxes again?

Comment: What do you mean you can't _"access the text in my NewPointName textbox"_? What are you trying to do and how is that not working/what result do you get? -- Also, why are you calling `Application.DoEvents()` everywhere?

Comment: I hope you are aware that in the bottom of your code you clear the value of your `NewPointName` text box: `NewPointName.Text = "";`

Comment: I know, but they are overwritten in the UI of the program.

Comment: What do you mean with "overwritten"? That they are empty, or that your picture box is placed on top of them, covering them? If the former: that's how it works. If you change the `Text` property then the contents displayed in the UI will change as well.

Comment: No I mean I want to write text in the textbox, but it's not using that text, it's using the empty string I put in. And if I leave that out, it's using the last thing that I wrote in the box, not the new one. It's blocking the outside control of the textbox.

Comment: I still don't understand... So if you click the text box after running this code, you cannot write anything in it with your keyboard? Have you checked so that you haven't accidentally set its [**`ReadOnly` property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.readonly(v=vs.110).aspx) to `true`? Also remove `Application.DoEvents()`. It has no business being there and you should infact not be using it at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved the problem, I just had to leave out the `InitializeComponent()`, then it worked. Turns out that if you do that, the already existing components get blocked and can't be changed in any options of themselves anymore.

Comment: Ah, I missed that line as I was reading from my phone. Yes, you shouldn't call `InitializeComponent()` multiple times. All it does is setting the properties for the controls added through _**the designer**_. `InitializeComponent()` should only be called **once**, and that is in your form's constructor.